# Piping terminal output to file from within C program

Tags: c, file-io, printf, output

I would like everything that gets output to stdout to also be saved in a file in my C code. I know that I can do this by calling the process on the command line and piping it to a file:

```
 myprogram.exe 1>logfile.txt
```

for example. But I am wondering if there is a way to do this from within the C code itself. Is there a function in the printf() family that can output to both the terminal and a specified file with the same arguments?

If not, what would be the syntax required to write my own printf()-style function which calls both printf() and fprintf() within it, using the same argument style as printf()?

Comment: Read about [variadic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic). Then read about [`vprintf` and `vfprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, that's a C++ solution. The OP's question is tagged C.

Comment: Take a look at [the source code for tee](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-170/tee/tee.c). That might give you something to work from.

Comment: @RSahu Doesn't matter, the variadic functions are just the same and works just the same in C.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am familiar in principle with variadic functions but have never used them, so I will have to give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the suggestion to use variadic functions:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

/*
 * Not all compilers provide va_copy(), but __va_copy() is a
 * relatively common pre-C99 extension.
 */
#ifndef va_copy
#ifdef __va_copy
#define va_copy(dst, src) __va_copy((dst), (src))
#endif
#endif

#ifdef va_copy
#define HAVE_VACOPY 1
#endif

int
ftee(FILE *outfile, const char *format, ...)
{
    int result;
    va_list ap;
#if HAVE_VACOPY
    va_list ap_copy;
#endif

    va_start(ap, format);

#if HAVE_VACOPY
    va_copy(ap_copy, ap);
    result = vfprintf(outfile, format, ap_copy);
    va_end(ap_copy);
    if (result >= 0)
        result = vprintf(format, ap);
#else
    result = vfprintf(outfile, format, ap);
    if (result >= 0) {
        va_end(ap);
        va_start(ap, outfile);
        result = vprintf(format, ap);
    }
#endif
    va_end(ap);
    return result;
}
```

That can be used like the standard `fprintf` function in that you specify an output file, except it will also write the normal output to `stdout`. I attempted to support relatively recent compilers that still didn't have a `va_copy()` macro (defined in C99) such as that which comes with Visual Studio 2012 (VS2013 finally has one). Some C runtimes also conditionally define `va_copy()` such that compiling with strict C89/C90 mode enabled will make it undefined while `__va_copy()` may remain defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fprintf() function, which is quite similar to printf() in the way it works.

Here is an example:

```
FILE *fp;
int var = 5;
fp = fopen("file_name.txt", "w");// "w" means that we are going to write on this file
fprintf(fp, "Writting to the file. This is an int variable: %d", var);
```

The output on your file would be this:

```
This is being written in the file. This is an int variable: 5
```

N.B: Opening the file using ***w*** as parameter will destroy the file's content every time you open it.

*For writing to a file you have to use file operation commands, it is not possible to write to a file using printf (it prints only to the stdout). You can use:*

```
sprintf(buf,"%d",var);  //for storing in the buffer
printf(buf);       //output to stdout
fputs(buf, fp);   //output to file
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I know how to use the printf() family of functions, what I was hoping for was a single print function that outputs to two different streams, eg stdout and a FILE pointer that I specify, at the same time.

Comment: I have editted my answer have a look, I hope you got your answer.